# Why strstr() search for null string always return true?

Tags: c

Why does the `strstr` function always return true for the following code:

```
void main(){
    char* a = "qweqweqweqweqweqw";
    char b[5] = {0x00,0xff,0xaa,0xbb,0xcc};
    printf("%p",strstr(a,b));
}
```

When I replace the null string `0x00` to something else the error goes away.
Please help me to understand why?

Comment: The empty string is a substring of every string. ISO C: "If s2 points to a string with zero length, the function shall return s1." (But `0x00` is not a "null string", it's a string terminator.)

Comment: You are essentially terminating the string in the very first char of the char array. Naturally, `strstr()` assumed this is a null string then.

Comment: The `strstr` function is only for use on C-style strings. Your `b` is just an array of characters and not a C-style string. (Think about it -- what else could `strstr` do? It has no idea how big `b` is. What would `strlen(b)` return?)

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? If you are looking for a sequence of arbitrary bytes (including zeroes) within a larger sequence, use `memcmp` instead of `strstr`.

Comment: ah ye I think i'll go with memmem

Answer (score 5):

From `strstr`:

> ```
> char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
> ```
>
> The `strstr()` function finds the first occurrence of the substring
>   needle in the string haystack.

Since strings are null-terminated in C and `0x00` denotes a null byte, `b` is effectively `""`.
Searching for an empty string **always** yields true, so your program will always find the substring.

`strstr`is designed for strings. No string contains `0x00` as a character, so `strstr`will not work here. You'll need to write a custom search function like `binbin`, which seeks binary data in binary data. The function signature might be like this:

```
unsigned char* binbin(const unsigned char* haystack, size_t haystack_len,
const unsigned char* needle, size_t needle_len);
```

A size is passed here because we cannot null-terminate the data.

Answer (score 2):

by putting `0x00` on the beginning of your string `b`, you essentially created a null-string, since it is terminated in the very first char. you see `0x00` or `'\0'` is a string terminator, indicating the end of a string for all c string functions. So `strstr()` reads only the first char, assumes the string ends there, and since there was nothing there before that, assumes the string is a null-string, and a null string is part of every single string there is.

Comment: Is null-string a standardese term? I've never heard it before... no criticism here, BTW.

Comment: @cad My professor introduced it as string consisting only of a null terminator before.

Comment: Normally that's called an empty string, not a null string.

Comment: @nos afaik both of these mean exactly the same.

Comment: Logically, it's an empty string, implemented in C as a null-terminated string of length 0, or you could also say a null-terminated empty string. The term "null-string" may be too easily confused with a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Many platforms have the function memmem:

```
void main(){
  char* a = "qweqweqweqweqweqw";
  char b[5] = {0x00,0xff,0xaa,0xbb,0xcc};
  printf("%p", memmem(a,strlen(a), b, sizeof(b)));
}
```